# Nested table in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have transaction tables called `MaterialRequest` and `MaterialRequestDetails`.

What I want to check my query and review that it's correct way to do this.

Below are tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Unit](
    [UnitNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Unit] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Unit] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UnitNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Location](
    [LocationNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Location] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Location] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LocationNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item](
    [ItemNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ItemDescription] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [UnitNo] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Item] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ItemNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Item]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Item_Unit] FOREIGN KEY([UnitNo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Unit] ([UnitNo])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Item] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Item_Unit]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MaterialRequest](
    [MaterialReqNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MaterialReqNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [RequestDate] [date] NULL,
    [LocationNo] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MaterialRequest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MaterialReqNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MaterialRequest]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MaterialRequest_Location] FOREIGN KEY([LocationNo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Location] ([LocationNo])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MaterialRequest] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MaterialRequest_Location]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MaterialRequestDetails](
    [MaterialReqDetailNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MaterialRequestNo] [int] NULL,
    [ItemNo] [int] NULL,
    [Qty] [numeric](18, 3) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MaterialRequestDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MaterialReqDetailNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MaterialRequestDetails]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MaterialRequestDetails_Item] FOREIGN KEY([ItemNo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Item] ([ItemNo])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MaterialRequestDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MaterialRequestDetails_Item]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MaterialRequestDetails]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MaterialRequestDetails_MaterialRequest] FOREIGN KEY([MaterialRequestNo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[MaterialRequest] ([MaterialReqNo])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MaterialRequestDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MaterialRequestDetails_MaterialRequest]
GO
```

and the query for review is

```
SELECT     dbo.MaterialRequest.MaterialReqNo, dbo.MaterialRequest.MaterialReqNumber, dbo.MaterialRequest.RequestDate, dbo.MaterialRequest.LocationNo, 
                      dbo.MaterialRequestDetails.MaterialReqDetailNo, dbo.MaterialRequestDetails.ItemNo, dbo.MaterialRequestDetails.Qty, dbo.Item.ItemCode, dbo.Item.ItemDescription, 
                      dbo.Item.UnitNo, dbo.Location.Location, dbo.Unit.Unit
FROM         dbo.MaterialRequestDetails RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Item LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Unit ON dbo.Item.UnitNo = dbo.Unit.UnitNo ON dbo.MaterialRequestDetails.ItemNo = dbo.Item.ItemNo RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Location LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.MaterialRequest ON dbo.Location.LocationNo = dbo.MaterialRequest.LocationNo ON 
                      dbo.MaterialRequestDetails.MaterialRequestNo = dbo.MaterialRequest.MaterialReqNo
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to explain what results you are expecting. The joins are (at least to me) rather usual. I presume you have some reason for them rather than a more normal syntax (like `inner JOIN  dbo.MaterialRequest  ON dbo.MaterialRequest.MaterialReqNo = dbo.MaterialRequestDetails.MaterialRequestNo
inner JOIN  dbo.Item             ON dbo.Item.ItemNo                   = dbo.MaterialRequestDetails.ItemNo
inner JOIN  dbo.Location         ON dbo.Location.LocationNo           = dbo.MaterialRequest.LocationNo
inner JOIN  dbo.Unit     ON dbo.Unit.UnitNo                   = dbo.Item.UnitNo`

Comment: many thanks for reply, the query will show all record from Trn_MaterialRequest table and data related to the reference

Answer (score 1):

Three part naming in the list of columns has been deprecated. You should become familiar with aliases and use them. It makes your code a lot easier to read.

That wall of text query would look something like this with aliases.

```
SELECT mr.MaterialReqNo
    , mr.MaterialReqNumber
    , mr.RequestDate
    , mr.LocationNo
    , mrd.MaterialReqDetailNo
    , mrd.ItemNo
    , mrd.Qty
    , i.ItemCode
    , i.ItemDescription
    , i.UnitNo
    , l.Location
    , u.Unit
FROM dbo.MaterialRequestDetails mrd
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Item i ON mrd.ItemNo = i.ItemNo 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Unit u ON i.UnitNo = u.UnitNo 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Location l
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MaterialRequest mr ON l.LocationNo = mr.LocationNo 
                                    ON mrd.MaterialRequestNo = mr.MaterialReqNo
```

Right joins are almost always a red flag that something is not quite right. They are unusual and uncommon for sure. Most people just don't think like that. There seems to be something a bit off in your query but not totally sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, what i want to achieve is Get all the records from master table. example i have transaction tables MaterialRequest and MaterialRequestDetails, i want to write the query to show me all the records which is available on MaterialRequest and MaterialRequestDetails as FK reference and join them into master table to get the master data